# Using mySQL to load strange characters in R

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to load some data into `R` from a database using `mySQL`. It is currently going pretty well, except for the fact that some characters are being returned as question marks. For example, "jurić" in the database returns "juri?" in `R`.

My code looks as follows:

```
library(RMySQL)
db_connection <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'myuser', password 'mypassword', dbname = 'mydb', host = 'myhost')
rs <- dbSendQuery(db_connection, 'SELECT * FROM  `articles`')
articles <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
```

The resulting dataframe looks exactly as I want it to look, except for some the question marks in places where there should be letters. The weird thing is that some strange characters (for example é,ö,š,ø) are correctly displayed.

How can I make sure that all the characters are loaded? The collation used in the column in the database is `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: have you already tried to set your connection to utf8? Try : `dbSendQuery(db_connection, "SET NAMES UTF8; ")`

Comment: I have tried this, but it results in even more strange characters. The characters that were correctly processed first are not correct anymore (é is now ã©) and the ć is ä‡. I think the latin1 character set is used, but I am unable to change it.

Comment: Very strange. When I add the suggestion of Cocca and write the data to a txt file, all the strange characters are shown correctly and it is shown that the encoding is UTF-8. However, in `R`, the characters are still not shown correctly. After some googling I think this has to do with my system locale, but I am unable to change this to the correct one.